# what is the stack of threads for each semaphore

Tags: linux, multithreading, stack, semaphore

I know each thread has its own stack.

And my textbook says:

**Suppose that a particular semaphore implementation uses a LIFO stack of threads for each semaphore. When a thread blocks on a semaphore in a P operation, its ID is pushed onto the stack. Similarly, the V operation pops the top thread ID from the stack and restarts that thread**

what I don't understand is. since each thread uses its own stack to store its thread ID, and obviously threads don't share stack with others, so what does LIFO stack of threads mean? because a thread only put its thread onto the stack which won't contain another thread's id, why use LIFO term here, isn't that LIFO only be meaningful if we can push multiple items on stack?

Answer (score 1):

Your OS needs to know **which all threads are waiting for each semaphore**. To maintain that list, OS can use a `LIFO` data structure i.e. `stack` for each semaphore object.

Do not confuse it with `stack` of each thread.

Answer (score 0):

> what I don't understand is. since each thread uses its own stack to store its thread ID, and obviously threads don't share stack with others, so what does LIFO stack of threads mean?

Threads can shared their stacks with others if they want. Each thread having its own stack is no impediment to one thread accessing another thread's stack.

> because a thread only put its thread onto the stack which won't contain another thread's id, why use LIFO term here, isn't that LIFO only be meaningful if we can push multiple items on stack?

The fact that each thread has its own stack doesn't prevent others from existing for other purposes. That each thread has its own stack has no effect on what a sempahore can do or not do with a stack.

Think about apples. You can have them. You can share them. You can eat them.

Now, say there are ten children and each has their own apple. Does that mean there cannot exist an eleventh apple that's shared? Does this prevent them from doing other things with other apples? No, it does not.

So, yes, each thread has its own stack. And they can also share those stacks if they want.

But also, a semaphore can have a stack. And it can do anything it wants with that stack. This has nothing whatsoever to do with any other stacks that threads might have.